# Relations between $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I'm trying to find some example for those two question. But it's not familiar for me, so hard to find. Please some Hint for those.

> Suppose $\mu(X) = \infty$ and there exist sets $A_1, A_2, A_3, \dots$ in $M$ such that $\mu(A_k) < \infty$ for every $k$ and $X= \bigcup\limits^\infty_{k=1} A_k$. ($X$ is $\sigma$ -finite)
>
> (a) Prove that there exist disjoint sets $B_1, B_2, B_3, ...$ in $M$ such that $1\le \mu(B_k) < \infty$ for every $k$ and $X= \bigcup\limits^\infty_{k=1} B_k$.
>
> (b) Prove that there exists $f \notin L^1(X)$ such that for all $1<p\le \infty$, $f \in L^p(X)$.

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

For part $(a)$, consider $B_1=\bigcup_{n=1}^{m}A_n$ such that $\mu(B_1) > 1$. This can be done since $\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n) = \infty$ (Why?). Then define $B_{k+1} = \bigcup_{l=1}^{m_k}A_{l} \backslash B_k$ choosing $m_k$ such that $\mu(B_{k+1}) \geq 1$.

For part $(b)$, when $X = (0,\infty)$, we can consider $f(x) = \dfrac1x$. You can generalize this to any $\sigma$-finite space $X$. Once you obtain your $B_k$'s, let $f = \dfrac1{k\mu(B_k)}$ on the set $B_k$.

Comment: For part (a), nothing ensures that the measures of these sets $B_k$ are at least $1$. For (b), why this example should be a hint for the general case is not clear to me.

Comment: @did Oh. I didn't see $1 \leq \mu(B_k)$ condition for part $a$, though it can be fixed. For $b$, yes it is not clear to me how to generalize this to any $\sigma$-finite set $X$.

Comment: @did For part $b$, once we obtain the $B_k$'s, let $f = \dfrac1{k\mu(B_k)}$ on the set $B_k$. Does that sound fine?

Comment: That's much better...

Answer (score 0):

take $X=\mathbb{R}_+$ with normal topology the first cover could be
$A_n=[n-1,n+1]$ hence $ A_n \cap A_{n+1}=[n,n+1] $ and then
$B_i$ could be $ [n,n+1)$ and for $f$ take $ f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ then
$\int_{0 }^{\infty} |f(x)| = \infty$ and for any $p>1$
$\int_{0 }^{\infty} |f(x)|^p$ is finite.

Comment: This is homework you should *not* be giving out answers.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the homework was about the abstract case so I tried to provide an example, but then again the example may lead in an straight forward way to a solution of the homework...